# Como programar C# no Linux usando Glade?

Tags: linux, mint

Boa noite pessoal. Estou iniciando em Linux usando a versão mint.
Descobri o aplicativo Glade, que programa interfaces graficas. Eu ja descobri como fazer a interface mas gostaria de saber como posso usar o C# nela.

Até o presente momento eu apenas instalei o aplicativo usando:

```
sudo apt-get install glade
```

[image: a onde eu parei]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, dois conceitos devem estar claros:

> Glade é um construtor de interface gráfica para GTK+. <sup>[1](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glade)</sup>
>
> GTK+ é um toolkit multiplataforma para a criação de interfaces gráfica. <sup>[2](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK)</sup>

Basicamente o Glade cria um arquivo XML, que deverá ser lido pelo [GtkBuilder](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html).

GTK+ é implementado em C, com [conexões/ligações para outras linguagens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_language_bindings_for_GTK), sendo estas mantidas por outros projetos, como por exemplo o [Gtk#/Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/).

Assim se o seu objetivo é criar uma interface Gtk, utilizando a linguagem de programação C#, é a este que você deve recorrer.

Comment: Obrigado, era isso que eu queria saber.